# Coercing two columns into 1 column of factors and 1 column of corresponding values in R for data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I am trying to change a dataframe of "a" format to the dataframe of "b" format.

i.e. data frame "a" as input and data frame "b" as output.

```
a <- data.frame(rowname = c("gene_a","gene_b","gene_c"),
            p_val = c(1, 1, 1),
            p_val_adj = c("1","1","1"),
            cluster = c(0, 1, 2),
            pct.1 = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.4),
            pct.2 = c(0.6, 0.6, 0.6))

b <- data.frame(rowname = c("gene_a", "gene_a", "gene_b", "gene_b", "gene_c", "gene_c"),
            colname = c("cluster_0_pct1", "cluster_0_pct2", "cluster_1_pct1", "cluster_1_pct2", 
                        "cluster_2_pct1","cluster_2_pct1"),
            values = c(0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6))
```

To describe this data frame editing in my own words, I want to merge the cluster column and the names of pct.1 and pct.2 columns such that it gives me a column like

```
colname = c("cluster_0_pct1", "cluster_0_pct2", "cluster_1_pct1", "cluster_1_pct2", 
                    "cluster_2_pct1","cluster_2_pct1")
```

and create a value column with the corresponding values from either pct1 or pct2 columns, depending on the colname i.e. cluster_1_pct1 should have a value of 0.4.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I've sort of ran out of luck trying to use dplyr functions like rownames_to_column(), pivot_longer ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with 'pct.1', 'pct.2' specified as 'cols' in `pivot_longer` and `paste` the 'cluster', 'name' columns to create the 'colname'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
a %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = pct.1:pct.2) %>%
     transmute(rowname, colname = str_c('cluster_', cluster, name), values = value)
#  rowname        colname values
#1  gene_a cluster_0pct.1    0.4
#2  gene_a cluster_0pct.2    0.6
#3  gene_b cluster_1pct.1    0.4
#4  gene_b cluster_1pct.2    0.6
#5  gene_c cluster_2pct.1    0.4
#6  gene_c cluster_2pct.2    0.6
```

---

Or with `gather`

```
a %>%
    gather(key, values, pct.1:pct.2)  %>%
    transmute(rowname, colname = str_c('cluster_', cluster, key),values )
```